# PouchDB Polling Mode

Tags: pouchdb

According to the CouchDB documentation, a CouchDB notification feed can be received in different ways: through ordinary polling, longpolling and by maintaining a single open HTTP-connection. The mechanism PouchDB uses for continuous replication seems to be long-polling.

Is there a way to choose continuous replication with ordinary polling? So that PouchDB would implement the polling loop and provide our application code with the same interface as if we would be using long-polling.

Or is our only option to implement this polling loop ourselves if we don't want to use long-polling?